# How to fetch data from secure shared path using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, rundeck

My shared path is

```
Path = //vs-kstp-eligha/testing-folder/build
```

My python script is

```
os.listdir(path)
```

I am running my script on windows server
I can able to access shared path from windows server and able to get data

But when I run same script from rundeck running on Linux server

I am getting access denied issues

Is there any way to access shared path by giving username and password or any alternative way?

I have tried in all possible ways by trying slashes in shared path as below

```
//vs-kstp-eligha/testing-folder/build
////vs-kstp-eligha//testing-folder//build
\\vs-kstp-eligha\testing-folder\build
\\\\vs-kstp-eligha\\testing-folder\\build
```

In rundeck I have already added windows and some some scripts are running through rundeck
When coming to shared path only I am getting access denied.

Comment: How is this "secure shared path" implemented? Lots of things can happen magically on Windows machines that are joined to a domain, which your Linux machine presumably is not.

Comment: A job output with the error stack could help. Also, include a minimal reproducible example (a basic job definition to test). Is that path stored in a Rundeck option? Could you test directly using the inline-script step?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value in an option and then call it on an inline script step using the following format: `@option.myoption@`.

Take a look at this job definition [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPfY8.jpg):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: a2d2355f-bda4-4d05-ba50-4efa6b065754
  loglevel: INFO
  name: PythonTest
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: mypath
    value: //path/to/file
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .py
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: print("@option.mypath@")
      scriptInterpreter: /usr/local/bin/python
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: a2d2355f-bda4-4d05-ba50-4efa6b065754
```

Another tip: make sure to define the python interpreter in the script "Invocation String" textbox and the `.py` extension in the "File Extension" textbox. Both options are available after clicking the "Advanced" link in the inline-script step.